# java android why picture's dimensions are distorted and how to use actual size?

Tags: java, android, size, imageview

for example, in my layout xml file i use 2 png - one is 188 pixels high, second is 180.
first I use in a tile , second I simply stretch with android:scaleType="fitXY".

But when I take a screenshot from eclipce - it's totally different - first is 138 pix on screenshot, second - 95 - so the difference in heights are much bigger than it should be

android:layout_height="wrap_content" in both cases, so they both should be actual size. 
I dont want them both to be actual pixels on screenshot from eclipse, I want they heights ratio to each other be the same.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my project,i used "weight" to proper different android device,first you should set height is 0px;then set weight for imageview with proper value, and keep "fitxy" or use "centerCrop" to crop this image;